# Read .sql into R with Spanish characters (á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ, etc)

Tags: r, postgresql, character-encoding, odbc

So, I've been struggling with this for a while now and can't seem to google my way out of it. I'm trying to read a .sql file into R, I always do that to avoid putting 100+ lines of sql in my R scripts. I usually do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(<CONNECTION ARGUMENTS>)

query <- read_file("path/to/script.sql")
df <- as_tibble(dbGetQuery(con, query))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

However, this time my sql script has some Spanish characters in it. Say something like this:

```sql
select tree_id, tree
from forest.trees
where species = 'árbol'
```

When I read this script into R and make the query it just doesn't return anything, **but if I copy and paste the sql script into an R string it works!** So it seems that the problem is in the line where I read the script into R.

I tried changing the string's encoding in a couple of ways:

```r
# none of these work
query <- read_file("path/to/script.sql")
Encoding(query) <- "latin1"

query <- readLines("path/to/script.sql", encoding = "latin1")
query <- paste0(query, collapse = " ")
```

Unfortunately I don't have a public database to offer to anyone reading this. I'm connecting to a postgreSQL 11 database.

--- UPDATE ----

I'm on a windows 10 machine, with US locale.

When I use the `read_file` function the contents of `query` look ok, the Spanish characters print out like they should, but when I pass it to `dbGetQuery` it just doesn't fetch anything.

I tried forcing encoding "latin1" because I found online that Spanish characters tend to fix in R when doing that. When doing this, the Spanish characters print out wrong, so I didn't expected it to work, and it didn't.

The character values in my database have 'utf-8' encoding.

Just to be completely clear, all my attempts to read the .sql script haven't worked, however this does work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(<CONNECTION ARGUMENTS>)

query <- "select tree_id, tree from forest.trees where species = 'árbol'"
# df actually has results
df <- as_tibble(dbGetQuery(con, query))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: What encoding did you use on that file that contains non-ASCII characters? Are you sure that it's latin-1? Are you on Windows? Does the contents of `query` look correct? How are character values encoded in your data base?

Comment: @MrFlick I updated the question with all the information, thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, if you take the `query` from the chunk that works, and then do `write_lines(query, "test.sql")` and then read it back in and run it with `query <- read_lines("test.sql"); dbGetQuery(con, query)` does it work? On windows everything is latin-1 by default. You will probably need to convert to utf-8 to work with the database connection. What does `Encoding(query)` return before you try to set it "latin-1".

Comment: @MrFlick I actually already tried that and it didn't work, I didn't post it as something I tried because it sounded dumb when I was writing the question :P

Comment: `Encoding(query)` returns "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time to think about it, I wondered why the solution proposed by MrFlick didn't work. I checked the encoding of the file created by this chunk:

```r
query <- "select tree_id, tree from forest.trees where species = 'árbol'"
write_lines(query, "test.sql")
```

After checking what encoding did *test.sql* have, it turned out it was ANSI, but it didn't look right. So I manually changed my original script.sql encoding to ANSI. After that it worked totally fine.

This solution however, didn't work when I cloned my repo on an ubuntu environment. In ubuntu there was no problem with the original 'utf-8' encoding.

Hope this helps anyone dealing with this in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding statement is telling R how to interpret the filename, not its contents. Try this instead:

```
filetext <- readLines(file("path/to/script.sql", encoding = "latin1"))
```

See this answer for more details:[R: can't read unicode text files even when specifying the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305884/r-cant-read-unicode-text-files-even-when-specifying-the-encoding)

Comment: that also didn't work, `dbGetQuery` doesn't return anything :/
The question that you're referring to only deals with reading the characters into R, which I have no problem doing using `read_file`. The problem is when I try to send that string as a query.