# How to read csv file with unknown formatting and unknown encoding in R Program? (example file provided)

Tags: r, csv, encoding, rstudio, readr

I have tried my best to read a CSV file in r but failed. I have provided a sample of the file in the following Gdrive link.

[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k73vDiolf9PujCdDZMOP2T5iyiDuOWWU/view?usp=sharing)

I found that it is a tab-delimited file by opening in a text editor. The file is read in Excel without issues. But when I try to read it in R using "readr" package or the base r packages, it fails. Not sure why. I have tried different encoding like UTF-8. UTF-16, UTF16LE. Could you please help me to write the correct script to read this file. Currently, I am converting this file to excel as a comma-delimited to read in R. But I am sure there must be something that I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks 
Amal

PS: *What I don't understand is how excel is reading the file without any parameters provided? Can we build the same logic in R to read any file?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Windows-related encoding problem.

When I open your file in Notepad++ it tells me it is encoded as UCS-2 LE BOM. There is a trick to reading in files with unusual encodings into R. In your case this seems to do the trick:

```
read.delim(con <- file("temp.csv", encoding = "UCS-2LE"))
```

(adapted from [R: can't read unicode text files even when specifying the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305884/r-cant-read-unicode-text-files-even-when-specifying-the-encoding)).

BTW "CSV" stands for "comma separated values". This file has tab-separated values, so you should give it either a .tsv or .txt suffix, not .csv, to avoid confusion.

In terms of your second question, could we build the same logic in R to guess encoding, delimiters and read in many types of file without us explicitly saying what the encoding and delimiter is - yes, this would certainly be possible. Whether it is desirable I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, @peter for your reply. 
Your solution worked. Perfect. The issue was that the file encoding is UTF-16LE, which read_delim cannot read at present. I used the base read.delim and file() to specify the encoding: `read.delim(file("temp.csv", encoding = "UTF-16LE"), sep = "\t")` This did the trick for me.

Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction.